# Evaluation of general solution of $~{\mathrm{d}^2 y\over\mathrm{d}x^2}-y=e^{-x}~~\text{with}~~y(0)=a,~~~y'(0)=b~$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
{\mathrm{d}^2 y\over\mathrm{d}x^2}-y=e^{-x}~~\text{with}~~y(0)=a,~~~y'(0)=b
$$

Evaluate necessary and sufficient condition(s) of $~a,b~$such that bounded solutions exist for$~x\geq0~$

**My tries:**

$$\begin{align}
y&=Ae^{-x}~~\leftarrow~~A~\text{ is a constant}\\
y'&=-Ae^{-x}\\
y''&=Ae^{-x}\\
y''-y&=0\\&\neq e^{-x}\\
&\text{This way doesn't work} 
\end{align}$$

I even can't reach to a general solution.

I want your help.

**ADDING**

Owing to Átila Correia, I got the following for the i.v.p.
$$
\begin{cases}
y=e^{-x}\left\{-{1\over 2}(x+k)-{1\over 4}+e^{2x}\text{const}\right\}\\
k=b-a\\
\text{const}={a\over 2}+{b\over 2}+{1\over 4}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Using $y=z\,e^{-x}$ leads to $z''-2z'=1$ Then $p=z'$ gives $p'-2p=1$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
y'' - y = e^{-x} & \Longleftrightarrow (y'' - y') + (y' - y) = e^{-x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (y' - y)' + (y' - y) = e^{-x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u' + u = e^{-x}\\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{x}u)' = 1\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{x}u = x + k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow u = xe^{-x} + ke^{-x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y' - y = xe^{-x} + ke^{-x}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{-x}y)' = xe^{-2x} + ke^{-2x}
\end{align*}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: "HINT - *solves problem completely*"

Comment: @kevinkayaks thanks for pointing that out. Even though I have not solved it entirely, I agree there is no much left to do. I removed the **HINT** part in accordance to your comment.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I got following as a general solution.
$$
y=e^{-x}\left\{-{1\over 2}(x+k)-{1\over 4}+e^{2x}\text{const}\right\}
$$
I will continue my work for solving the initial value problem.